# функция для проверки

Tags: jquery, html, css

Функция для проверки "если value="1900" то добавить и показать классы" на jquery JavaScript

```
$('.error').removeClass();
$('.errorT').css('display','none');

<div class="error">
        <select class="year" name="year" > 
        <option value="-1" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1900">1900</option>
        </select>
        <span class="errorT">Ошибка</span>
    </div>
```

Как сделать выборко значения value?

Comment: http://www.webnotes.com.ua/index.php/archives/699

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/Jfk7P/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KiTE/KPnap/)

HTML

```
<div class="error">
    <select id="year" name="year" > 
        <option value="-1" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1900">1900</option>
    </select>
    <span id="msg_year" class="msg">Ошибка</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.msg {
    display:none;
}
.error {
    display:inline;
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#year').change(function(){
        if( $('#year').val()=='1900' ){
            $('#msg_year').addClass('error');
        }else{
            $('#msg_year').removeClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.year').change(function(){
    if($(this).val()==1900){
        $('.errorT').show();
    }        
});
```

- **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**

думаю добавить класс вы сами сможете

- **[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**
- **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)**
- **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)**

Answer (score 1):

к примеру:

```
$('select.yaer').cange(function(){  
     val = $('div.error select.year option:selected');
     alert('value='+val);
});
```

Comment: внутри .change текущий селект доступен через this

Comment: спасибо, не знал